# Internal CSS not overriding external CSS for class

Tags: css, stylesheet, external, internal, overriding

I need my "column" class in the internal CSS to float center while the external CSS has it set to left.

Here is my CSS file:

```
body { text-align: center; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }  
#report { width: 1269px; margin:  auto; float: left;
}

div.column{  margin-top: 10px; padding: 0px 0px; float: left; }
div.first{ padding-right: 8px; border-right: 1px grey solid; }
div.second{  margin-left: 8px; 
}
...
```

Here is my HTML with internal CSS:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dual Server Report</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ServerReport.css">
    <style type="text/css">
    div.column{ float: center; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="report">
<h1>Automated PowerShell Install Report</h1>
<h2>This report was ran: 07/07/2015 09:03:21</h2>

    <div class="column">
...
```

I checked out these three similar questions but nothing I tried worked.
[Internal Stylesheet NOT overriding External stylesheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703587/internal-stylesheet-not-overriding-external-stylesheet)
[“Inner” CSS Not Overriding “Outer” CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458602/inner-css-not-overriding-outer-css)
[Overriding External CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204933/overriding-external-css)

Edit:
I remembered looking up the "float" property yesterday but I did not remember what I found; I feel pretty silly for posting this before going to double check. It makes sense that float would not have a center property.

I'll leave this up in case anyone in the future makes a similar mistake. Thanks to everyone who answered for being so respectful in pointing out this error I should have found on my own.

Comment: There isn't such a thing as "float: center".

Comment: Try loading your "external" CSS file after the "internal" one. And for your "you learn something new every day" lesson, read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property value of `float: center` does not exist.

The [`float`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-position) property has four values: `left`, `right`, `none`, and `inherit`.

Comment: Well I definitely feel silly now. Thanks CitizenDelta & Tyler, and everyone else for taking the time to point this out. Just one of those things I should have known but it's been so long I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

The only valid values for float are: **left, right, none, inherit**.

So this code will be skipped and not override the css file.
Please look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) for more information on the float property.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like `float: center` in CSS

**Another way to do it**

Change your CSS under the html page

```
div.column
{
 float: none;
 margin: auto;
 width: 200px; /* set the width (Except 'auto') */ 
}
```